# Javascript's Modulus broken?

Tags: javascript, operators, modulus

I just found out that when you type `Math.pow(5,25) % 5` in the console, it returns 2. This also happens when you first solve `Math.pow(5,25)` (`298023223876953150 % 5 = 2`). But that number is clearly divisible by 5, because it is a power of 5...

Has anyone an idea what is going on here?

(I also saw that the outcome of `Math.pow(5,25)` is wrong, it is 25 higher than the real number, does someone knows how this works too?)

Comment: It's because the genuine result of `Math.pow(5, 25)` is well into the region where not all integers can be accurately represented by IEEE-754 double-precision floating point numbers, so it gets rounded to the nearest one (`298023223876953150` ), which is a different number. There's a duplicate here somewhere...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I saw. I realised. I removed. I stoopid.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: LOL We've all done it.

Comment: it was not evolutionxbox but me, I removed my comment

Comment: `(298023223876953150 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) === true`